# Type 1 Error and Power

Tags: statistics

X is sample of size 1 with pdf $f(x|\theta)=\frac{x-\theta}{10}, x=\theta+1, ..., \theta+4$

For $H_0: \theta=0$ versus $H_1: \theta \neq 0$, the test rejects when $X \notin 2,3,4$. For type 1 error, and the power when $\theta=-1$.

$\alpha = P(X \notin 2,3,4 | \theta=0)=1-\sum_{\theta=2}^{\theta=4}\frac{x-\theta}{10} = \frac{1}{10}$

$\beta(\theta)$ = 1-P(type 2 error) = $1-P(X=1|\theta=-1) = 1-(\frac{1-(-1)}{10})=0.8$

I think $\alpha$ is correct, but I'm unsure on the power

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $\theta = -1$, $X$ takes value $0, 1,2,3$.

The rejection region is $\{2,3,4\}^c$.

Hence we will reject if we see $x \in \{0,1\}$ and do not reject when $X \in \{2,3\}$.

$$\beta = 1 -  \left( \frac{3+4}{10}\right)=1-0.7=0.3$$

Comment: I see it now, thank you!

Comment: Hey, I made a careless mistake earlier